# ExecuteScalar return wrong value

Tags: c#, sql

Good day 
I am working on login page where the user will be able to login and then change password after first login.Then, the user will be able to login to the system with the new password.
 I found out that ExecuteScalar will help me to make the codes working perfectly. But, I am facing now that ExecuteScalar  is returning wrong values where the user will be able to change the password but it will not allow him to redirect to the main page.

I have tried to change in if statement but still it showing me wrong results

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=TOWELL\XPEDEON;User ID=xplive;Password=xplive");
 try {
                    con.Open();
                    if (attemp < 3)
                    {

                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cmd.CommandText = ("select count (*) from log_sup where ENTITY_DIVISION_CODE = '" + textBox1.Text + "'and DX_NUMBER = '" + textBox2.Text + "' ");
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        da.Fill(dt);
                        int result = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

                        if (result > 0)
                        {
                            Form3 F3 = new Form3();
                            F3.Show();
                            this.Hide();

                        }
                        else if(result == 0)
                        {
                            recby = textBox1.Text;
                            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
                            f2.Show();
                            this.Hide();
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("WRONG PASSWORD, THIS IS YOUR  " + attemp + " ATTEMPT  ");
                        }   
                    }
                    else if (attemp == 3)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("LOGIN EXCEED , PLEASE CONTACT THE ADMIN TO RESET YOUR ACCOUNT LOGIN");
                        textBox1.Enabled = false;
                        textBox2.Enabled = false;
                        label2.Enabled = false;
                    }         
                    attemp++;
                }
                catch (Exception) {
 }
            con.Close();
```

[the table query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7TJ0.png)

where the user after changing the password, it will marks as 1 in order to check that the password has changed

Comment: What are you checking with this line: `if (result > 0)`?

Comment: What is it returning and what do you expect it to? Also what’s the use of the data adapters etc when they’re not used anywhere? Also *always* use parameters, don’t put values from user to SQL string.

Comment: it should return for me a redirect page (main page ) if the password has been changed

Comment: I think to help we would need to see the table you are querying and the values. you are filling a datatable and not using it, have you stepped through the code and checked what the value is in the dt using the data visualizer?

Comment: You might want to use parameterized SQL queries to avoid the obvious SQL injection problems with your current code. I'm not saying this will fix your issue, just being helpful.

Comment: What is `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` returning? What do you expect it to return?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing the query:

1. `Count(*)` can be expensive (you may want to scan the *entire table*), when all you want is an answer for "if there *any* record such that..." - you can well stop early.
2. Let's *parametrize* the query (just imagine that I put `"123'; delete from log_sup; --"` into `textBox1.Text`)

**Code:**

```
 ...
 cmd.CommandText = 
   @"select 1
       from log_sup
      where ENTITY_DIVISION_CODE = @prm_ENTITY_DIVISION_CODE
        and DX_NUMBER = @prm_DX_NUMBER";

 //TODO: cmd.Parameters.Add("param_name", RDMBS_TYPE) is a better choice
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_ENTITY_DIVISION_CODE", textBox1.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_DX_NUMBER", textBox2.Text);

 using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
   if (reader.Read()) {  // We've succeeded in reading (at least) one record
     Form3 F3 = new Form3();
     F3.Show();

     this.Hide();
   }
   else {                // the cursor is empty
     recby = textBox1.Text;

     Form2 f2 = new Form2();
     f2.Show();

     this.Hide();
   } 
 }
 ...
```